# Setting unknown property

Tags: php, yii2

Model:

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;

class User extends \yii\base\Model
{
    public $login;
    public $password;
    public $repassword;
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['login', 'password', 'repassword'], 'required'],
            [['login'], 'match', 'pattern' => '/^[A-Za-z0-9_]+$/u', 'message' => 'Логин может содержать буквы цифры и "_" '],
            [['login'], 'unique', 'Логин уже используется'],
            [['login'], 'filter', 'filter' => 'trim'],
            [['password'], 'string', 'min' => 4, 'message' => 'Слишком короткий пароль'],
            [['repassword'], 'compare', 'compareAttribute' => 'newPassword', 'message' => 'Пароли не совпадают']
        ];
    }
}
?>
```

Controller

```
public function actionReg()
{
    $model = new User;
    return $this->render('reg', [
        'model' => $model
    ]);
}
```

View

```
<?

use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
use yii\helpers\Html;

?>
<? $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'login-form']); ?>

<?
    echo $form->field($model, 'login');
    echo $form->field($model, 'password');
    echo $form->field($model, 'repassword');
?>


<? ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

getting error:

> PHP User Error – yii\base\ErrorException
>
> Exception (Unknown Property) 'yii\base\UnknownPropertyException' with
>   message 'Setting unknown property: yii\validators\UniqueValidator::0'

at line

```
echo $form->field($model, 'login');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

seem this

```
   [['login'], 'unique', 'Логин уже используется'],
```

is not a valid validator.

Try remove it or defined a new one in this format

```
 ['a1', 'unique', 'targetAttribute' => 'a2']
```

Probably this `'Логин уже используется'` is not a valid  attribute

Comment: `[['login'], 'unique', 'message' => 'Логин уже используется']`